# list of InPortal's

Tags: reactjs, portal

I'm trying to use [react-reverse-portal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-reverse-portal) for an infinite scroller (to cache expensive components). So far so good.

For conciseness, I generate a list of InPortals to activate them, and keep them up to date - without a div wrapper for each.

1. Is this risking a memory leak, or does react clean out InPortals not included in a list iteration?
2. Is there a way to include the key argument (`ReactDOM.createPortal(children, container, key`) using InPortal? I'm presuming this would help react maintain a clean list of active portals

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, it's just a matter of adding a `key` attribute to the InPortal component.